Apache Error 500: Problem with cgi script execution on python 2.4
When trying to access a python file via http request. I get an error:
Internal server error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to fulfill your request.

Please contact the server administrator at you@example.com and let them know when the error occurred and anything you may have done to cause it.

More information about this error may be available in the server's error log.

Apache/2.0.54 (Unix) Server at 

The configuration file I have looks like this:
ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "/usr/htdocs/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "/usr/htdocs/cgi-bin">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Allow, Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

And call the object.py file itself as follows:
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-                                      
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print 'Content-type: text/html\n\n\n'
print '<html><body>hello scritp</body></html>'

I was executing the python file through the console and everything was outputting correctly there. But for some reason apache server doesn't want to execute the file. There is an error in the logs:
[Sat Dec 17 12:09:44 2016] [error] [client 192.168.3.164] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/usr/htdocs/cgi-bin/object.py' failed
[Sat Dec 17 12:09:44 2016] [error] [client 192.168.3.164] Premature end of script headers: object.py


I'd appreciate a hint. My python version is 2.4. I also checked the path to the intopreter via the which console command.

It is 2024. If you are still running Python 2.4 this is the least of your problems. It's too old to be included on https://devguide.python.org/versions/ but 2.6 was end-of-lifed in 2013 and the final Python 2.x release on January 1st 2020 after an extremely prolonged and agonizing period on artificial life support.

(Also, seriously, the log entries are from 2016. Is this some sort of joke?)

Unfortunately no, not a joke. But it's a challenge. Unfortunately, I can't understand. Where I might have gone wrong.

The error message seems to suggest /usr/bin/python does not exist, or is shielded from the web server somehow.

I found where the file is located using the which command. So everything is set correctly there.

For the record, which is not portable and dependable, but that's probably unimportant here. Can you run a command within the web server's security context to check whether the path is accessble from there?

Yes. I tried running the program through the context menu, it works.

Which context menu?

error shows that /usr/htdocs/cgi-bin/object.py doesn't exist - so you have to check if put file in correct folder. File need to be executable - it may need chmod +x /usr/htdocs/cgi-bin/object.py
